# Populating a HTML dropdown box with values from an array

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been looking at quite a few questions with this and I'm still getting problems.

Here is the code:

```html
<body>

<?php
//To start, there is a form with a dropbox and a button, which will have the various functions that can happe
?>

<form action="search_start.php" method="post">
    Function <select name="Functions">
    <?php
    $fns_to_choose = array(
        "Option 1" =>"Get A Monthly Report",
        "Option 2" => "Track One Ship Over Time",
        "Option 3" => "Track Multiple Ships Over Time",
        "Option 4" => "Get Ships Over Time For One$
    ?>
    <select> 
        <?php
        foreach ($fns_to_choose as $key => $value)  {
            echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>'; 
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

What happens is that instead of using the elements of the array to populate the dropdown, the elements are just 'echoed' beneath an empty dropdown, which looks like this:

[image]

From what I've seen from the other answers on this site, the options should be populating the form, rather than just being underneath it.

Any suggestions are absolutely welcome.

I feel like this is like, the most rudimentary thing and I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few syntax errors, fixed as below, can you try again?

```html
<body>


<?php

//To start, there is a form with a dropbox and a button, which will have the various functions that can happe

?>

<form action="search_start.php" method="post">
<!-- here -->

<?php

$fns_to_choose = array("Option 1" =>"Get A Monthly Report","Option 2" => "Track One Ship Over Time", "Option 3" => "Track Multiple Ships Over Time", "Option 4" => "Get Ships Over Time For One") // here

?>

<select name="Functions"> <!-- here -->
        <?php
                foreach ($fns_to_choose as $key => $value) 
                {
                        echo '<option value="' . $key .    '">' . $value . '</option>'; 
                }
        ?>
 </select>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `<select>` tags resulting in nesting, which is not allowed. Remove one of them and that should solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed,  I got up, walked around, came back, and saw the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So,

after I posted this I found the answer. The problem is I try to effectively create two dropdowns. So I deleted the first one, and now it works just fine.

I've left this up here because.. well.. frankly, my silliness might help somebody else.